# How to update state in child component using React Router params?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to update my state based on a Link. It is dependent on the param.ID that is passed down through the Route.

> Problem is I'm not sure how to get that info to the parent component.

The state has an array of objects. Clicking the Link changes one of the object's properties. But I need to know which link was clicked in order to know how to update the state. Ideally I'd have this function in the parent component:

```
updateState() { 
    this.setState({
        data: ????
})
```

But I'm not sure what to set the data as without knowing the param beforehand. If I pass an event handler to the onClick function in the Link I just get the html.

I've tried changing the child component into a class component and updating the state from there but that doesn't work. Even in `componentDidMount`. I get a massive error saying I'm updating the state too many times and it will result in an **infinite loop.**

Answer (score 0):

Compare the previous previous props in component did update to the current props.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
     if(prevProps.value !== this.props.value){
         this.setState({value: this.props.value)}
}
```

Untested... but this is the gist of it.